# What is the function of From and To at the DATA section of smtp mail?

Tags: smtp

I am trying to understand using smtp to send mail. I saw an example and it is like this:

```
 HELO yourhost.yourdomain.edu
 MAIL FROM: <carol@yourhost.yourdomain.edu>
 RCPT TO: <msgs@host1.somewhere.com>
 RCPT TO: <alice@host2.somewhere.com>
 DATA
 Date: Sun, 30 Nov 98 nn:nn:nn EST
 From: Carol <carol@yourhost.yourdomain.edu>
 To:   <msgs@host1.somewhere.com>
 Cc:   <alice@host2.somewhere.com>
 Subject: Update

 Mike: Cindy stubbed her toe.  Bobby went to
    baseball camp.  Marsha made the cheerleading team.
    Jan got glasses.  Peter has an identity crisis.
    Greg made dates with 3 girls and couldn't
    remember their names.
 .
 QUIT
```

What i am confused about is, we already have MAIL FROM and RCPT TO at the beginning, why do we also have From:, To: and Cc: again at the DATA part? What is the difference between RCPT TO: at the header and To: at the DATA section? And if we assume we sent mail succesfully with these commands, what will be the output? I mean what is it that the receiver sees?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of the message is transmitted in the DATA section of the protocol.

However, SMTP uses the MAIL FROM and RCPT TO to record the envelope information (that may be different to the actual message). This is most apparent in mailing list delivery where the envelope is addressed to the actual recipient, while the body of the message often only contains a distribution list name.

The recipient will only be able to see the content in the DATA. The envelope is lost when the MTA (message transfer agent) places the content into the mail store for the MUA (message user agent) to retrieve and display to the user.

This has produced years of problems (and endless spam) due to the possibility of mismatched values, but was seen as the most appropriate mechanism when the [RFC-822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) structure and [SMTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt) transport protocol and their successors were prepared.

The actual transport does not require that the message is formatted in any particular form. This is something that is validated by the receiving system to ensure that only well-formed mail is accepted for local delivery.

Answer (score 3):

Basically: an SMTP server, like Postfix, is only interested in the envelope (MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands), a mail user agent, like Thunderbird, is only interested in the message content (From:, To: and Cc headers).

This is very similar to snail mail, the addresses on the envelope and the included letter are frequently identical, but not necessarily.

The reverse-path in the envelope says where to send a bounce message if a problem occurs. It may match the From header, maybe not. For example a secretary sends the mail in the name of his boss. The reverse path will contain the email address of the secretary, the From header will contain the name and mail address of the boss. It is also different in case of mail lists, as it was written by Pekka.

The forward-paths (RCPT TO parameters), are the actual destinations. The SMTP server is not interested in whether it has to deliver the mail to somebody because he is in the To, or because he is in te Cc list. In case of the Bcc addresses, naturally there is no Bcc header in the mail content all! After all it is *blind* carbon copy. But the Bcc-ed recipients are listed as forward paths in the RCPT TO command, so the SMTP server will know about them, the users will not.